# How do I check my String so that Only letters and the $ symbols are allowed?

Tags: java

In the normalizeDiscountCode verify that only letters or the $ character are used. If any other character is used, throw a IllegalArgumentException with the message Invalid discount code.

I tried this

```
char[] chars = code.toCharArray();
if (! Character.isLetter(chars.length) || code != "$"){
    //if (code.matches("[a-zA-Z$]")){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
}

this.discountCode = code.toUpperCase();
return code.toUpperCase();
}
```

and this

```
if (! Character.isLetter(code.length()) || code != "$"){
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
}

this.discountCode = code.toUpperCase();
return code.toUpperCase();
}

public class Order {
private String itemName;
private int priceInCents;
private String discountCode;

private String normalizeDiscountCode(String code){
    //char[] chars = code.toCharArray();
    if (! Character.isLetter(code.length()) || code != "$"){
        //if (code.matches("[a-zA-Z$]")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
    }

    this.discountCode = code.toUpperCase();
    return code.toUpperCase();
}

public Order(String itemName, int priceInCents) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public int getPriceInCents() {
    return priceInCents;
}

public String getDiscountCode() {
    return discountCode;
}

public void applyDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
    this.discountCode = discountCode;
    this.discountCode = normalizeDiscountCode(discountCode);
}
}

public class Order {
private String itemName;
private int priceInCents;
private String discountCode;

private String normalizeDiscountCode(String code){
    //char[] chars = code.toCharArray();
    if (! Character.isLetter(code.length()) || code != "$"){
        //if (code.matches("[a-zA-Z$]")){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
    }

    this.discountCode = code.toUpperCase();
    return code.toUpperCase();
}

public Order(String itemName, int priceInCents) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
    this.priceInCents = priceInCents;
}

public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}

public int getPriceInCents() {
    return priceInCents;
}

public String getDiscountCode() {
    return discountCode;
}

public void applyDiscountCode(String discountCode) {
    this.discountCode = discountCode;
    this.discountCode = normalizeDiscountCode(discountCode);
}
}
```

Comment: Your regex pattern `[a-zA-Z$]` only matches a single character. To match one or more, you can use `[a-zA-Z$]+`.

Comment: So you tried `code.matches("[a-zA-Z$]")`, but nether thought about adding a quantifier there to make it work?

Comment: Your condition is wrong. You throw the exception if *either* the character is not a letter *or* it is not `$`. Of course, letters are not `$`, and `$` is not a letter. It's supposed to be `&&`, not `||`. In addition, why are you checking the array's length? A length is not a letter. You should be checking each character.

Comment: Would I have to use a for each loop in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to use the foreach loop, something I always struggled with. I was having a hard time figuring out how to convert full Strings into char.

```
private String normalizeDiscountCode(String code){
    for (int i = 0; i < code.length(); i++){
        char c = code.charAt(i);
        if (! Character.isLetter(c) && c != '$'){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid discount code");
        }
    }
    this.discountCode = code.toUpperCase();
    return code.toUpperCase();
}
```